# Referencing the google-play-services library

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, libraries, google-play-services

I'm working on a project using the Google Maps Android API v2, and I have a problem when I start referencing google-play-services_lib. A red exclamation mark appears on my project icon, and I have an error message in the "Problems" tab (I'm using Eclipse) :

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Labo FMS\Documents\Applications\04-adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'
```

And, indeed, if I go to that folder, I see that there is no "google-play-services_lib.jar" file.

I've tried reinstalling the library, and I've noticed that when it's installing there's an error message at the bottom :

```
[2013-04-09 13:54:32 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-04-09 13:54:32 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2013-04-09 13:56:18 - MainActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

Anybody knows what it all means ?

Comment: google play services are build with the target api 8. And it look like you dont have android-8 platform. Try install that from sdk manager or change the target api from project properties

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`google-play-services_lib` not found `target 'android-8'` because it was not installed in your `Android SDK`.

change your Android `target 'android-8'` to any other using.

```
Your Project--->Right Click-->Properites-->Android-->Select Google API 15(whatever you have)-->ok
```

Or

Add this in Android manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

you can add target SDK any which you have but it must be `Google API`.

Comment: Just to be more precise in case someone has the same problem : what you need to do is to open the AndroidManifest.xml file in the google-play-services_lib folder in the Package Explorer, and replace <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/> with <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

Comment: (or whatever SDK version you're using)

Comment: Editing the Google library is not likely to be a good idea in the long run. Better to simply provide the correct dependencies as per the other answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15902392/1662031 - this solves both problems in that it then allows Eclipse to create the required jar file.

Comment: As @user2350653 suggested, you may need to restart Eclipse afterward.  I needed to

Answer (score 4):

Your second message means that you don't have the necessary file for `SDK android-8`, what you need to do is to open the `SDK Manager` and download the SDK version you would like to have (For example):

[image]

After that you would have the needed jar file, So you can add it to your Google Map project.

Comment: your answer is correct, but dude, you have to update your stuff!

Comment: heh, yes you are right. didn't open SDK Manager in a while now : \

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but everything is up to date in the SDK manager. But I already solved the problem, so it's okay ^^

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that your answer addresses both issues in the question.

Answer (score 4):

What solved it for me was updating some packages ('sdk platform-tools', and 'sdk build-tools' were updated from 16 to 17) in the SDK manager.
After that, everything was ok.

I spent nearly half a day to resolve this...
I realize this will probably not help anyone, but for the remote 0.1% chance that this DOES help someone I decided to write up my answer here.

Hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 3):

Tried the best answer above but it still didn't work. After trying all the others and continue searching in other places but for no good.

What eventually solved the issue was to RESTART ECLIPSE and clean (after executing what's written in the best answer above).

Comment: This was my issue as well. "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Answer (score 1):

in your manifiest file add this inside

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When importing the project I checked Copy project into workspace checkbox. That solved it for me, which is quite strange as a matter of fact, but we all know eclipse goes crazy all the time. Btw, I want a working Eclipse for this Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when updating the Android SDK components via the Android SDK Manager.  Previously, I had imported a couple of Google libraries (Google Play Services, etc) into my Eclipse workspace and selected the **Copy projects into workspace** option.  The upgrade broke this since the imported libraries' versions were a different version from the main SDK.

Deleting the copied projects from Eclipse, then re-importing them directly from the SDK directory fixed this issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Project --> Clean. It worked for me. Good luck !