# google maps android v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I start map project and follows the instruction of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

when I add this code snippet i got an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Error**

```
[2014-04-21 06:32:21 - appcompat_v7_3] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Umer Mir\workspace\appcompat_v7_3\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-04-21 07:14:23 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-04-21 07:14:26 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'
[2014-04-21 07:45:30 - Mapsproject] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2014-04-21 07:45:41 - Mapsproject] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Comment: What is minium API level in your manifest ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing the google-play-services library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902222/referencing-the-google-play-services-library)

Comment: Project--->Right Click-->Properites-->Android-->Select Google API version -->ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your Android target `android-8` to any other.

`Your Project--->Right Click-->Properites-->Android-->Select Google API 15(whatever you have)-->`

Or

Add this in Android manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

you can add target SDK any which you have but it must be `Google API`.